# How to persist a chrome extension overlay between page changes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The Google is failing me since anything about "persist overlay" and "extension" gives me results about how to prevent overlays using extensions... Not quite what I'm after.

I'm building an extension that shows a sidebar dialog. This is loaded as a content script via my `manifest.json` given a page's URL. This sidebar will provide meta information about the underlying page as well as actions a user can take. I'd like this sidebar to persist between page loads but it seems like it is re-called and reopened every time the page changes. Since part of the sidebar contains an iframe, that iframe is reloaded as well and it creates a less-than-ideal experience for the user.

Is there a way to persist an overlay using strictly a Chrome extension?

Comment: There's no such thing in Chrome. DOM elements belong to their page so they are destroyed along with the old page. Some other browsers (Firefox, Opera) have a sidebar API.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks - looks like what i'm after would be a Chrome App, maybe used in conjunction with an extension